# BigQuery fails to save view that uses functions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

We're using BigQuery with their new dialect of "[standard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/)" SQL.
the new SQL supports inline functions written in SQL instead of JS, so we created a function to handle date conversion.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
  STR_TO_TIMESTAMP(str STRING)
  RETURNS TIMESTAMP AS (PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ', str));
```

It must be a temporary function as Google returns `Error: Only temporary functions are currently supported; use CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION`
 if you try a permanent function.

If you try to save a view with a query that uses the function inline - you get the following error: `Failed to save view. No support for CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION statements inside views`.
If you try to outsmart it, and remove the function (hoping to add it during query time), you'll receive this error `Failed to save view. Function not found: STR_TO_TIMESTAMP at [4:7]`.

Any suggestions on how to address this? We have more complex functions than the example shown.

Comment: the only "workaround" I see is to submit feature request at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: The feature request for [permanent registration of user-defined functions](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=817) can be found in our issue tracker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the issue was marked as [resolved](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905921), BigQuery now supports [permanents registration of UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_function_statement).
In order to use your UDF in a view, you'll need to first create it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `ACCOUNT-NAME11111.test.STR_TO_TIMESTAMP`
    (str STRING) 
    RETURNS TIMESTAMP AS (PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ', str));
```

- Note that you must use a backtick for the function's name.
- There's no `TEMPORARY` in the statement, as the function will be globally registered and persisted.
- Due to the way BigQuery handles namespaces, you must include both the project name and the dataset name (`test`) in the function's name.

Once it's created and working successfully, you can use it a view.

```
create view test.test_view as
select `ACCOUNT-NAME11111.test.STR_TO_TIMESTAMP`('2015-02-10T13:00:00Z') as ts
```

You can then query you view directly without explicitly specifying the UDF anywhere.

```
select * from test.test_view
```

[image: querying a BigQuery view that uses a permanently registered UDF]

Comment: Where is the documentation link for BigQuery permanent function, it is missing here (at least for now): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

Comment: I think it's located here. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_function_statement

Comment: Since the namespace is quite lengthy. Is it possible to declare functions as variables? Say calling my-long-names-project.my_lengthy_dataset.my_long_function_name as ‘func’?

Comment: @Benjamin you can do that with a temporary function. you can call a temporary function without the namespace.  so either create your temporary function inline before your SQL statement or create a temporary function with a short name to call the permanently registered function with the long name.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_function_statement , the functionality is still in Beta phase but is doable. The functions can be viewed in the same dataset it was created and the view can be created.
Please share if that worked fine for you or if you have any findings which would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Saving a view created with a temp function is still not supported, but what you can do is plan the SQL-query (already rolled out for the latest UI), and then save it as a table. This worked for me, but I guess it depends on the query parameters you want.

```
##standardSQL
## JS in SQL to extract multiple h.CDs at the same time. 
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION getCustomDimension(cd ARRAY<STRUCT< index INT64, 
value STRING>>, index INT64)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
     for(var i = 0; i < cd.length; i++) {
     var item = cd[i];
     if(item.index == index) {
         return item.value
  }
}
return '';
""";

SELECT DISTINCT h.page.pagePath, getcustomDimension(h.customDimensions,20), fullVisitorId,h.page.pagePathLevel1, h.page.pagePathLevel2, h.page.pagePathLevel3, getcustomDimension(h.customDimensions,3)
FROM
`XXX.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
    ### rolling timeframe
    _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL YY DAY))
    AND h.type='PAGE'
```

Credit for the solution goes to https://medium.com/@JustinCarmony/strategies-for-easier-google-analytics-bigquery-analysis-custom-dimensions-cad8afe7a153

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a bit of code to make your answer even easier to find for people who might need this in future.